# Serial-port Datareceive

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm having a problem with serial port data.  I have designed a form where I have used a datareceived handler event and the whole of data needs to be printed in the RichTextBox placed in the form.  The problem is I'm only receiving the last bits of data on the RichTextBox, while the MessageBox that is provided with the code runs the whole of data in part.  Please suggest where I'm going wrong.Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        char po='\0';
        string indata,pi;
        string[] buffer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;

            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            po = Convert.ToChar(serialPort1.BytesToRead);


           indata = sp.ReadExisting();
           //return (indata);
                //for (int p = 0; p <= 256; p++) ;
                //MessageBox.Show(buffer[0]);



            //MessageBox.Show(indata);
            //richTextBox1.Text += indata;
            //richTextBox1.Text = indata;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            richTextBox1.WordWrap = true;
            richTextBox1.Text = indata;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What kind of data are you reading and how many bytes are being sent at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying This Code....

```
private string StrValue = "";
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, 
System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    double DouRWeight = 0;    
    try
    {
        DouRWeight = Val.ToDouble(Port.ReadLine());
        if (DouRWeight != 0)
        {
             this.Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate()
             {
                 StrValue   = Val.Format(DouRWeight.ToString(), "####0.000");
             }
        }
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        richTextBox1.WordWrap = true;
        richTextBox1.Text = StrValue ;
}
```

It's Completely Worked...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be appending the data each time data is received over the serial port, so perhaps you should change

```
indata = sp.ReadExisting();
```

to:

```
indata += sp.ReadExisting();
```

To hold all of the contents of the Serial Data, including historical data that was previously sent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already tried the above solution. In the debug mode I can see the complete data in the string "indata" but when the button is clicked to show the data into the richtextbox only some part of the data is showing.

Comment: I think Matthew is right. Subsequent data received events will overwrite previous `indata`. You can't guarantee that all data has been received when the `datareceived` event first occurs.

Comment: @SubhodeepBhattacharjee - Matthew is correct in that you must concatenate the string where you are reading.  One other thing to look at is that you are accessing a variable from two different threads in an unsafe manner.

Comment: I followed Matthew's tips and but indata += sp.ReadExisting() is not working,so I modified it a bit and took another string.                                          indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            indata1 += indata;  Now that's working perfectly.